# jQuery.get() Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error Only On Some Resources

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, svg

Bit of a weird one! I'm trying to import SVG code to our site, hosted by a third party, from a PHP script that pulls in the XML from our in-house server. So essentially all of the calls go to the same file but using a different query parameter to load the SVG.

So, almost randomly, sometimes I'm getting this...

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

...on a subset of the calls (sometimes none, sometimes a few but rarely all of them). Even between page refreshes. So I'm just wondering why it doesn't just blanket work or not work.

Here's the code from the PHP file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$svg = $_GET['svg'];
$file = "/path/to/images/social/$svg";

if(file_exists($file)){
    $svg = file_get_contents($file);
    $svg = preg_match('/(<svg.*<\/svg>)/is',$svg,$matches);
    echo $matches[0];
} else {
    echo "0";   
}
```

And the JS:

```
$('.footer-social a').each(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var f = '//js.example.com/svg.php?svg='+$.trim(el.attr("class"))+'.svg';
    $.get(f, function (data) {
    if(data!="0"){
        el.html(data);
    } else {
        console.log(f + " not found");
    }
    });

});
```

Comment: try installing Allow-control-Allow-Origin [CORS] plugin in chrome and try

Comment: Is there any more code before the `header` call? You can check if the headers have already been sent using `headers_sent()`.

Comment: @jeroen that's the whole file!

Comment: Also just noticed that if I refresh the PHP file (if directly called in the browser) after a while I get a 403...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sorted - turns out it was due to **mod_evasive** being a little too harsh. Now optimised the variables in the config file and it's running fine.

This also sorted an issue we were having with **OpenCart** and the AJAX checkout, if anyone ever stumbles across this.